# JWT Example - "Error while requesting an Access Token"

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, docusignapi

I'm reviewing the JWT Access token flow for DocuSign. I've downloaded their example code to run, however I'm unable to obtain an access token after updated the DS_CONFIGs.

I'm using an organization grant for this user.  It looks like if I pass in the integrator key as both *clientId* and *userId* I can obtain an *ACCESS_TOKEN* however, then the `getUserInfo` call fails.

I've double checked that my application is been authorized for `signature impersonation`  via *org -> applications*.

Code

```
DS_CLIENT_ID=TEST-5***c76f6
# API username Guid
DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID=c92***f60
```

Docusign UI

```
Integrator Key: TEST-5***c76f6

User ID: c9***f60
```

With all the grants and configs I'd expect it to just pass, but there might be some details I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organization Consent requires a Claimed Domain, and only applies to users under that domain. Have you claimed your domain in the Demo environment?

Comment: Thanks, I have not. I'll look into updating all that. Looks like isn't mentioned in the  (Obtaining Conest page) [https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#admin-consent-for-internal-applications] but in the (SSO page) [https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-domains]

Comment: Good point, I'll pass that feedback along to the devcenter folks. Looks like it does say "Note that these permissions apply to every user who is a member of the organization’s reserved domains." but it could probably do a better job of highlighting the requirement.